# Object javascript dont have build-in function hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, express

Here my code

```
console.log(typeof res.locals);
console.log(res.locals.hasOwnProperty('a'));
```

My result :

```
object
Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.locals.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

Note 1: res is response Object by Express;

I use Express 4.13.3 .Anyone know what problem here ?

### NOTE :

```
  var a = Object.create(null);
  var b = {};
  a.hasOwnProperty('test');
  b.hasOwnProperty('test');
```

I find bug here  Object.create(null) dont make Object javascript with buildin function

Comment: Can you add the object `res` or result of `console.log(res.locals);`

Comment: res is request object by express

Comment: @trquoccuong but the express' request object doesn't have a property named `locals`, what am I missing here?

Comment: sorry it is response Object by express, it similar with app.locals. In document they said it a javascipt object

Comment: Check my note, maybe a bug with javascript, Express use Object.create(null) to make Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.locals` [is defined in Express](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.13.3/lib/middleware/init.js#L31) as an object without a prototype:

```
res.locals = res.locals || Object.create(null);
```

By passing `null`, the object doesn't inherit any properties or methods, including those on `Object.prototype` like `hasOwnProperty`.

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(res.locals)); // null

console.log(Object.create(null) instanceof Object); // false
```

---

To use the method with `res.locals`, you'll have to access it through the `Object.prototype`:

```
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(res.locals, 'a'));

// or store it
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
console.log(hasOwnProperty.call(res.locals, 'a'));
```